# What are tha main differences between an ISO and a QCO2 image?

Tags: kvm, qemu

Are there any benefits of using .qcow2 over .img files when trying to create a VM .

I have a smallish debian .iso and have seen at least with .qcow2 that it is slow.

I also saw http://wiki.qemu.org/Features/Qcow3 and these two lines show up there :-

> near-raw performance, competitive with QED
>
> Performance analysis has shown that QCOW2 performance is significantly
>   worse than using raw files. Different approaches, including QED's
>   simplified metadata and fully asynchronous implementation, have proven
>   that a modern image format can achieve near-raw performance. Metadata
>   caching and batched updates can also improve performance but require
>   image format changes to be effective in all cases.
>
> Improving performance is the key motivation for a QCOW3 image format.

Can anybody comment. I am guessing that qcow3 is stil up in the air.

Comment: Perhaps, a better subject would be: "What are tha main differences between an ISO and a QCO2 image?"

Answer (score 8):

A `qcow2` file will generally be more space efficient than an equivalent image file.  While it is possible to create "sparse" image files, these are difficult to transfer in an efficient manner.  A `qcow2` relies on mechanisms other than sparse allocation to achieve "thin provisioning" and is thus easier to move around.

A `qcow2` file can be defined as a copy-on-write (COW) layer on top of a backing image (which can be either a raw file or another `qcow2` image). This can be incredibly useful when you want to boot several virtual machines from the same underlying image, but want each machine to be able to store it's own modifications (a feature called "snapshots"; you can read more details [here](http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/CreateSnapshot)).

On the other hand, as you have seen, a `qcow2` file may not be as performant as a raw image file.

Comment: hi larsks, `img` is suppported only by virtual box and `qcow2` is used only with virtual manager right... none of these hypervisors support both the formats right?

Comment: The `qcow2` format works primarily with QEMU/KVM, but raw images will work with just about everything (including QEMU/KVM, VMware, VirtualBox, etc).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need specific features of `qcow2` and want to use the VM for years, consider not to use `qcow2`. If you update the operating system frequently, or you have used many temporary files, the deleted files are likely not deallocated on your real hard drive. And you may end up with an image file bigger than raw files.

You can convert between image formats when required, if you have enough free space on your hard drive.